# mongoose - Combining data via aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this kind of data:

```
[
  { _id: ..., class: 'A', name: 'John Doe' },
  { _id: ..., class: 'A', name: 'John Snow' },
  { _id: ..., class: 'B', name: 'Joan Doe' },
  ...
]
```

I need to have an aggregated data for mongoose with the result as:

```
[
  { class: 'A', students: [
    { _id: ..., name: 'John Snow' },
    { _id: ..., name: 'John Doe' }
   ]},
  ...
]
```

How can I do this with aggregation in mongoose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aggregate pipeline would look like this,

```
[
    {
        $group: {
        _id:{ class: "$class" },
        students:{$push:{_id:"$_id", name:"$name"}}
    }
]
```

I believe for mongoose you'd do something similar to:

```
Model.aggregate({
        $group: {
        _id:{ class: "$class" },
        students:{$push:{_id:"$_id", name:"$name"}}
    })
.exec(callback)
```

Comment: Sweet. I didn't know how to use that `$push` thing.